# I am getting this background by default when i set up a new android studio project

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have been googling here and there trying to resolve this issue and have ended up nowhere.
It would be appreciated if someone can guide me
I think it has something to do with themes.xml
If anybody can guide me in the right direction, that would be appreciated

Default Project

[image]

Comment: Hi Tushar. The screenshot should be embedded into the post. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Please post here your new activity xml, I wonder if it's really by default.

You can easily change the background color by adding

```
android:background="@color/black"
```

at the start of your xml, or any other color beside black that is inside your res/values/colors.xml

[image]

[image]

it should fix it, I don't know why thats your default color.

you can also try to change your res/value/themes/themes.xml

```
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

this might be the default color of your background.